# Sharepoint properties update using Excel VBA

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, properties, vba

[image]

I am able to upload files to Sharepoint through VBA but I'm not able to update these properties to have their properties updated with 'Document Status' and 'Confidentiality' Fields.

Until these are updated, others are not able to see them.

Comment: take a look at this link [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200071/update-sharepoint-metadata-using-vbscript]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  .ContentTypeProperties as discussed in this thread.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406585/vba-set-custom-document-property

Comment: Did not work. Below line gives me a subscript out of range error.

Workbooks(SharepointAddress).CustomDocumentProperties("Document status").Value = Final

Answer (score 0):

Then try this link  [Update SharePoint Metadata using VBscript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200071/update-sharepoint-metadata-using-vbscript)

It should help.  Take special notice to the multiple choice information at the bottom if you are using that type of control.